# Changed Title and Meta description in Yoast seo for some pages, but it was not showing in the website even after google crawls the website.

Tags: title

Changed Title and Meta description in Yoast seo for some pages, but it was not showing in the website even after google crawls the website. Instead it was showing the same old title that we put in the head section for all pages of the website.Only that same tile is showing for all the pages

Comment: Do a CURL test and wait several weeks. Google ensures the changes are correct and intended so it can take a few weeks, with that said this question has been asked several times in various forms on Pro Webmasters, please use the search function and visit our help centre for additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the updated title and description metas when you look at the code on the page? If it is updated there then I would not worry too much. Google sometimes takes time to update those in SERP.